# How do I use a click event to navigate to another page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

I'm using vue-bootstrap, I have several cards, each with a button in them, every button in these cards should take me to a different form, the problem is that I don't know how to make these buttons take me to the URL where these forms are, here's my code:

```html
<b-card
  v-for="item in cards"
  :key="item.id"
  :title="item.title"
  :img-src="item.imagen"
  tag="article"
  style="max-width: 17rem;"
  class="card"
>
  <router-link :to="{name: 'signUp', params:{id:item.title}}">
    <b-button variant="primary" onClick="location.reload();" >Go {{ item.title }}</b-button>
  </router-link>
</b-card>
```

For some reason the `location.reload()` method on the `onClick` event sometimes allows me to see the forms.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by "location.reload() sometimes allows me to see the forms"?  if you're just trying to navigate to another page location.href="http://url" should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `location.reload()`, you should be using `window.location.href='path-to-form'`

Answer (score 0):

The `router-link` will redirect to the path `:to="{name: 'signUp', params:{id:item.title}}"` on click. You don't need to add the button click event inside.

If you're trying to navigate to the route `singUp` on clicking button, you can use

```
  <router-link :to="{name: 'signUp', params:{id:item.title}}" tag="button">
      Go {{ item.title }}
  </router-link>
```

OR

```
<b-button variant="primary" onClick="$router.push({name: 'signUp', params:{id:item.title}})" >Go {{ item.title }}</b-button>
```

Which will redirect you to the route with name `signUp`.